# Error when I open rviz

Tags: slam, navigation, rviz, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I have a question: when I launch a launch file to open rviz for hector slam, sometimes I have this message:

```
[rviz-4] process has died [pid 12780, exit code -11, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/rviz/rviz -d rviz_cfg.rviz __name:=rviz __log:=/home/user/.ros/log/3deb1b84-c78d-11e5-8892-0c607639bb9d/rviz-4.log].
log file: /home/user/.ros/log/3deb1b84-c78d-11e5-8892-0c607639bb9d/rviz-4*.log
```

What can be the reason? Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225441/error-when-i-open-rviz/) by [papaclaudia](https://answers.ros.org/users/25634/papaclaudia/) on ROS Answers with karma: 94 on 2016-01-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As described in this question: http://answers.ros.org/question/11064/list-of-possible-exit-codes-from-roslaunch/ ; exit code -11 indicates a segfault.

Segfaults are a pretty generic error, and there's no specific fix.

You might want to consult the rviz troubleshooting page: http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Troubleshooting or try running rviz in gdb.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [papaclaudia](https://answers.ros.org/users/25634/papaclaudia/) on 2016-01-31**:
Thank you so much!